# JavaScript Local Storage not showing the correct value in another file

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have three files

1. `main.js`
2. `index1.html`
3. `index2.html`

I want to get the length of the number of divs from `index2.html` and store it in `main.js`, so I can use it with `index1.html`. 
When I `console.log` it shows the correct value which is **24** in `index2.html`  but the value in `index1.html` is **0**.

I linked `main.js` to both HTML files

```js
var popC = $('body > div.pro-pop').length;
localStorage.setItem('popC', popC);
var unco = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('popC'));
console.log('unco:', unco);
```

Comment: You are trying to set the value before getting the value

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using jQuery in JavaScript that won't work 
but in pure JavaScript you can you local storage like this way. 
Thank You! Hope it helps you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Store
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
  // Retrieve
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `localStorage` save the values per domain. not per page. if you want the values to be different in different pages, you need to give it different keys. you can try prepend the `pathname` before the key, so in each page it will be different.

```
 localStorage.setItem(document.location.pathname +'popC', 9);
 var unco = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem(document.location.pathname + 'popC'));
 console.log(unco);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your main.js contains this below js code  - I suggest you to not to include this in index1.html because it updates your value again.  Localstorage data is based on the domain you can create it on any page and retrieve it on any page with the same domain.

```
       var popC = $('body > div.pro-pop').length;
       localStorage.setItem('popC', popC);
       var unco = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('popC'));
       console.log('unco:', unco);
```